# Custom String representation of an Object in Java

Tags: java, string, object, tostring

Is there any way to change how an `Object` represents itself as a `String`?

For example, having `System.out.println(new JLabel());` output `Empty JLabel`.

Comment: Not on types you don't control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the toString() method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Empty JLabel";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Override the toString() method for that class

Answer (score 0):

you could override the `toString` method like this:

```
public class A {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empty A";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A());     // Empty A
    }
}
```